# Fetching recursive NSDictionaries and NSArray form JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, recursion

I am new to Xcode and I am trouble to find a solution to fetch NSArray and NSDictionaries from JSON. Please anyone help me.
Here my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "categoryID": "1",
        "category_parentID": "0",
        "category_name_english": "Telivision",
        "category_name_arabic": "واعتلاء ثم. حاول المضي عن أخر",
        "category_date_edited": "2013-02-16 06:55:02",
        "sub": [
            {
                "categoryID": "2",
                "category_parentID": "1",
                "category_name_english": "Sharp",
                "category_name_arabic": "واعتلاء ثم. حاول المضي عن أخر",
                "category_date_edited": "2013-02-16 06:55:02",
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "categoryID": "5",
                "category_parentID": "1",
                "category_name_english": "LG",
                "category_name_arabic": "",
                "category_date_edited": "2014-05-22 00:00:00",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "categoryID": "7",
                        "category_parentID": "5",
                        "category_name_english": "LG 1",
                        "category_name_arabic": "",
                        "category_date_edited": "2014-05-22 00:00:00",
                        "sub": []
                    },
                    {
                        "categoryID": "8",
                        "category_parentID": "5",
                        "category_name_english": "LG 2",
                        "category_name_arabic": "",
                        "category_date_edited": "2014-05-17 00:00:00",
                        "sub": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryID": "3",
        "category_parentID": "0",
        "category_name_english": "Computer",
        "category_name_arabic": "واعتلاء ثم. حاول المضي عن أخر",
        "category_date_edited": "2013-02-16 06:55:02",
        "sub": [
            {
                "categoryID": "4",
                "category_parentID": "3",
                "category_name_english": "HP COLOUR",
                "category_name_arabic": "واعتلاء ثم. حاول المضي عن أخر",
                "category_date_edited": "2013-02-16 06:55:02",
                "sub": []
            },
            {
                "categoryID": "6",
                "category_parentID": "3",
                "category_name_english": "dell",
                "category_name_arabic": "",
                "category_date_edited": "2014-05-16 00:00:00",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "categoryID": "10",
                        "category_parentID": "6",
                        "category_name_english": "i5",
                        "category_name_arabic": "",
                        "category_date_edited": "2014-05-09 00:00:00",
                        "sub": []
                    },
                    {
                        "categoryID": "11",
                        "category_parentID": "6",
                        "category_name_english": "i7",
                        "category_name_arabic": "",
                        "category_date_edited": "2014-05-23 00:00:00",
                        "sub": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryID": "12",
        "category_parentID": "0",
        "category_name_english": "Mobile",
        "category_name_arabic": "",
        "category_date_edited": "2014-05-15 00:00:00",
        "sub": []
    }
]
```

My code is here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RADataObject *category;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in JSONArray) {
        NSArray *subArray = [dict valueForKey:@"sub"];
        if(subArray.count ==0) {
            category = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:[dict valueForKey:category_name_english] children:nil];
        }
        else {
            category = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:[dict valueForKey:category_name_english] children:[self getSubCategories:subArray]];
        }
        [mutableAddArray addObject:category];
    }
    self.data = [mutableAddArray copy];
}

-(NSArray *)getSubCategories:(NSArray *)subArray
{
    NSMutableArray *duplicate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *dct in subArray) {
        [duplicate addObject:[dct valueForKey:category_name_key]];
    }
    NSArray *returnArray = [duplicate copy];
    return returnArray;
}
```

Is it possible using recursion?

Comment: in which key u need for retrieve

Comment: I want to retrieve value for key "category_name_english" and "sub".

Comment: What data structure are you trying to extract the information into?  It certainly has a recursive structure, so you could use recursion, but you need to define an appropriately recursive data structure to extract into

Comment: value for "category_name_english" should be NSString and value for "sub" should be NSArray

Comment: What @Paulw11 said -- It's (apparently) a recursive model, easily and naturally handled by a recursive algorithm, but you need to have a target data model that is similarly recursive.  No black magic involved -- just requires thought.

Comment: It sounds like you need to define a data object that has two properties - a category string and a sub-category array - the array will contain 0 or more instances of the data object

Comment: @Binni.. i had answered firstly and correctly but still you have not accepeted my answer and also not upvoted... why so

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ! Do run it and hope it help you out.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)parsingWithJsonArray:(NSArray *)array
{
   for (dictionary in array)
  {
    NSDictionary *categoryEnglishDict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"category_name_english"];

    [mutableArray addObject:categoryEnglishDict];

    NSArray *subArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"sub"];

    [self parsingWithJsonArray:subArray];
  }

  return mutableArray;  //This mutable array would contain category english language.
}
```

Anything else let me know.

Comment: [dictionary objectForKey:@"category_name_english"] returns NSString and I want that string and that's subArray at same time. Is it possible? @walle84

Comment: You could add that string in mutable array and as the function would return the mutable array containing all strings. Just give it a run with edit as your required.

Comment: @Binni your welcome and also don't forget to vote up and chose it as right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code might work for your.. not checked..

```
-(void)getSubCategories:(NSArray *)subArray
{
for (NSDictionary *myDict in subArray)
{

NSString *first = [myDict objectForKey : @"category_name_english"];
NSArray *myubArray = [myDict objectForKey : @"sub"];
if([mysubArray count])
 [self getSubCategories:mySubArray];


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should define a data storage object to store your categories -

SOCategory.h

```
@interface SOCategory : NSObject

-(NSArray *)subCategories;
+(SOCategory *)categoryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *categoryName;

@end
```

SOCategory.m

```
#import "SOCategory.h"

@interface SOCategory ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *subCategoryStore;

@end

@implementation SOCategory

-(id) init {
    self=[super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _subCategoryStore=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    return self;
}

+(SOCategory *)categoryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    SOCategory *newCat=[[SOCategory alloc]init];
    if (newCat != nil) {
        newCat.categoryName=(NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"category_name_english"];
        NSArray *subCats=(NSArray *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"sub"];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in subCats) {
            [newCat.subCategoryStore addObject:[SOCategory categoryWithDictionary:dict]];
        }
    }
    return newCat;
}

-(NSArray *)subCategories {
    return ([NSArray arrayWithArray:self.subCategoryStore]);
}

@end
```

Then, in your existing code you can populate an array of categories -

```
NSMutableArray *categories=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in JSONArray) {
   [categories addObject:[SOCategory categoryWithDictionary:dict]];
}
```

Note that this code doesn't report errors for malformed dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry.  It should be `newCat` not `self` - I have corrected the answer

Comment: I also changed the class name to avoid a conflict